# remote debugging in mvc.How to do it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Can anyone help me on how to do remote debugging in mvc4 application.Iam getting some error after hosting the app on the client server.Iam unable to create the same scenario in any of my dev environments.This is while calling my service.Can i debug the hosted app.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If it's a server-side error, you could point the client app on the client server to the server-side code on your local server and attach the debugger locally. Not sure if that is your scenario, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy task.

You need to carefully read and follow:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y7f5zaaa(v=vs.110).aspx